# Passing Data Between two different project exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a school project, a queuing management system in c#. I want to ask how pass data between two different exe projects. The first exe is where the monitor view which the queue numbers are displayed, and the other exe are where the buttons that calls for the next queue number.

Comment: What did your teacher explain about the queues? how have you made queues?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5830/Using-MSMQ-from-C

Comment: Does the monitor pull the values, or does the other exe push the values to the monitor? The answer to this can lead to different solutions.

Comment: the queue increments so the queue starts at a format of Q0000...so for the next queue it should be Q0001 ... then this queue number should be displayed in the monitor view which is in another project exe.

Comment: the monitor pulls the value.. then from the other exe , has a button that generates the queues to be displayed in the monitor which is in another exe